# What does the word 「ばっきゃろ」mean?

Tags: words, manga

Here is the situation in a manga which includes the word.

> A: ジョー　どないしよう？　みんながおきたら... みんなが目をさましはったら...
>
> B: **ばっきゃろ**！　さっきからなにをワナワナふるえてやがるんだっ。

I'm not sure if it is the same word as 「ばかやろ」.

**Extra question:** Is there any hidden meaning for the intention of changing the 「わなわな」 into Katakana form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ばっきゃろ is the change way of saying of 馬鹿{ばか}野郎{やろう}. It means same as 馬鹿野郎.

I think there isn't hidden meaning for the intention of changing the 「わなわな」 into katakana but I guess the writer may accent the sentence by using katakana because it is all written in hiragana except ワナワナ.